# Non commutative topological manifolds

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, banach-algebras

> Assume  that $A$ is  a  Banach  algebra with two closed two sided ideals  $I$  and  $J$ such that $I$  and  $J$ are  commutative  and $A=I+J$. Does this implies that $A$ is  commutative? For the  $C^{*}$  algebra, the  answer is  ["Yes"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998702/a-question-on-non-commutative-ring-or-algebra).

**The motivation:** A (noncommutative) compact n dimensional topological  manifold could  be  defined as  follows:

A  (non  commutative)  $C^{*}$ or Banach algebra  $A$  such that there  are ideals  $I_{k}$, $k=1,2,\ldots,n$ such that $A=I_{1}+I_{2}+\ldots I_{k}$ and  each $I_{j}$ is  isomorphic to $C_{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

But  the  above  answer in MSE shows that, in the context of  $C^{*}$  algebras, this  definition does  not  give  any non  commutative  example,.

> So  we  search  for  a non commutative  example  in  Banach  algebras.

**Note:** According to the comment on my MSE question: To what extent  Banach or  $C^{*}$  algebras whose underline Lie  algebras are  metabelian  are studied and  classified?

Comment: I just rolled back an edit which made one unnecessary change and which made one change which alters the meaning of one of the sentences

Comment: By the way, now you have changed this to Banach algebras I think this is **not** a good way to try to define a NC manifold. Recall that the Gelfand-Naimark correspondence only works for commutative C*-algebras. Also please read about general Banach algebras to see that they behave very very very very very very very very differently from the C*-case and to call a Banach algebra a noncommutative space is IMHO extremely tendentious

Comment: @YemonChoi I changed to "banach  algebra"  because a  user edit my  question from "Could  be  defined"  to "Is  defined". On the  other  hand we observe that for  $C^{*}$  algebra we  do not get a  non commutative object. In this  situation, is  not natural to extend to  Banach  algebra?

Comment: @YemonChoi Any way, if you do  not  like this  terminology, you could  read my questions  and  my  comments  as  follows:"Let  $A$ and  $B$ satisfies the  condition of the  definition. Is it true  to say $A\otimes B$  satisfies the  definition, too?

Comment: "In this situation, is not natural to extend to Banach algebra?" Not really, because the class of Banach algebras is much much bigger than the class of C*-algebras and they display much more varied behaviour. Surely you should think about what makes manifolds special kinds of topological spaces, and then try to encode that behaviour into some algebraic data -- but this seems to require some dense *-subalgebra of a $C^*$-algebra, not the use of Banach algebras which might not look remotely like any $C^*$-algebra

Comment: @YemonChoi  "Dense subalgebra" you mean smooth  function? So  what about the  algebraic  picture of topological  manifold  without smooth  structure?

Comment: Good point. OK, what you really need to do is work out a NC version of affine space - within the class of abelian $C^*$-algebras, what properties single out $C_0({\bf R}^k)$; and then what non-abelian $C^*$-algebras also satisfy those properties. **Then** you can start to ask about gluing, as in your original question.

Comment: @YemonChoi thanks  for this  comment. could  you more  explain and  clarify?

Comment: Well, a manifold is a topological space that looks locally like ${\bf R}^k$. So a NC manifold should be something that behaves "locally" (whatever that means) like a NC version of ${\bf R}^k$. Andreas Thom's answer shows that at least in the unital (i.e. compact) case there is nothing gained by trying to glue commutative pieces, so first work out what kinds of NC algebras would be good pieces

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Theorem** Let $A$ be a unital ring and $I_1,\dots,I_n \subset A$ be 2-sided commutative ideals such that $A=I_1+\dots + I_n$. Then, $A$ is commutative.

Proof: If $A=I_1+\dots+I_n$, then $1 = x_1+\dots+x_n$ for $x_i \in I_i$. But then,
$$1 = (x_1+\dots+x_n)^{n+1} \in I_1^2 +\dots+ I_n^2$$ and we conclude that $A=I_1^2 + \dots + I_n^2$.

Now, if $I \subset A$ is any abelian 2-sided ideal, then $I^2$ is central, since
$$a(bc) = (ab)c= c(ab) = (ca)b = b(ca) = (bc)a,$$
for any $a \in A$ and $b,c \in I$.
Since $A = I_1^2 + \dots + I_n^2$, $A$ is commutative. q.e.d.

If $A$ is not unital, then the same argument still shows that $A^{n+1} \subset A$ is central. If $A^2 \neq A$, then there are counterexamples - even for Banach algebras. For example, one can consider the non-abelian algebra $$A = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & * & * \\ 0 & 0 & *\\0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$$ of strictly upper-triangular $3\times 3$-matrices (with entries in a field), which is is a sum of two abelian ideals
$$I = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & * \\ 0 & 0 & *\\0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right), \quad J = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & * & * \\ 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your  interesting answer. So  We conclude that every non commutative  topological manifold, with the  above definition, is  necessarily "noncompact",i.e nonunital. Your example is  very interesting, however it gives the  empty manifold since the  multplication of each ideal is identically zero. So the next questions could be:What is  an example of  a  non commutative  manifold(non unital non commutative banach algebra)? Is it true to say that the tensor product of two manifold is  again  a manifold? Are there universal NC  manifolds $A_{n}$ such that....

Comment: ...such that every NC manifold is the  image of  some  $A_{N}$,  for  some $N\in \mathbb{N}$?(The analogy for   Withney theorem). Thanks  again for  your  answer.

Comment: So a  pre-question:Is the proper analogy of the Withney embedding theorem, true?Every manifold is  properly embedded in some  $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?